# Percentage calculation when size is same but weight is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the `weight` as a percentage of the total `weight` for each person.

Here's my data:

```
TableA

Name        |   Size    |   Weight  
------------------------------------  
Jamie       |   0.25    |   48  
Jamie       |   0.50    |   48  
Taylor      |   0.25    |   55  
Taylor      |   0.30    |   54  
Taylor      |   0.45    |   48  
Taylor      |   0.45    |   60
```

And here's the output I would like:

```
Name    |   Size        |   Percentage  |   Weight  
---------------------------------------------------------------  
Jamie   |   0.25        |   50%     |   48  
Jamie   |   0.50        |   50%     |   48  
Taylor  |   0.25        |   35.03%      |   55  
Taylor  |   0.30        |   34.39%      |   54  
Taylor  |   0.45        |   49.76%      |   108
```

**Eg :**
The total weight for Jamie is 96 (48+48), so I have to calculate his weight values as a percentage of 96 for each row.

And for taylor there is size 0.45 twice but with different weight so in the output it should sum the weight (48+60) and then (108/217)*100=49.76 as percentage

Comment: Ok where's your query that you've worked on that's having a problem or your results that aren't the way they're supposed to be?  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Dresden I have this query SELECT *, 100 * Weight/SUM(Weight) OVER(Partition By Name) AS Per 
   FROM worker but it is calculating the size twicw

Comment: You seem to have mistaken us for a SQL writing service, where you post your (extremely confusing) requirements and expect someone to churn out a SELECT statement for you. That's not how this site works. What attempts have you made to write a query yourself to get the results you want, and how **specifically** is it not working as expected? Please [edit] your question and add that information. While you're at it, add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using; functionality and syntax vary between the different engines. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite I am using MSSQL, and thanks for the inappropriate comments

Comment: Exactly how does this: `SELECT *, 100 * Weight/SUM(Weight) OVER(Partition By Name) AS Per FROM worker` calculate size twice because there are no calculations even referencing size. What is the problem with that query. Why does the weight column change in the final result for Taylor? (& by what logic?)

Comment: There's nothing *inappropriate* in my comments. You're expected to make a reasonable effort to solve the problem before asking here, and you've shown no effort to do so in your question. I asked you to edit and add it, along with a tag  (neither of which you've done). Rather than get snippy with people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem** when asked to provide information, it's in your interest to be polite and supply that information. But suit yourself. I've voted to close your question for the missing details. When you add them, I'll consider removing that close vote.

Comment: @KenWhite I am not trying to be rude here.And i have also added the tags

Comment: You're being rude by accusing me of posting *inappropriate comments*. I'm not quite new here; I'm well aware of what is and isn't appropriate, as well as what is expected of people asking for help. You're welcome to view my profile to see what experience I have here. And you **still have not** posted any effort to solve this yourself as I asked.

Comment: @KenWhite I am sure you are not new here, But I am new. My apology

Comment: @Red Devil in future post your attempted query into the question (not a comment under the question). I would not have answered either but as you did provide a query I could then see what else you needed - which wasn't much really. There are many you drop in to the site just expecting others to do their work for free - that is what we try to avoid and why we ask "what have you tried".

Comment: @Used_By_Already Agreed!! what you said i will make sure I post the query I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you need to summarize the source records first, then calculate the percentage. So, using a derived table I propose you sum the weight by name/size, and finish in the outer query.

```
SELECT
      name
    , size
    , 100 * Weight / SUM(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS Per
FROM (
      SELECT
            Name
          , Size
          , SUM(weight) AS weight
      FROM worker
      GROUP BY
            name
          , size
) AS w
```

Comment: @ KenWhite: Crickey. There is so little to say, the code is literally self-explanatory but as you insist.